# What is the view limit in Android xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Anyone have any idea about that in android layout XML, What is the maximum view limit that can be embedded into the XML? Is there any limit?

Comment: Firstly; I would ask why you would want to create lots of views on a mobile device? Assuming this is purely academic I would assume it is related to the amount of memory available.

Comment: i know this not a approach but still i want to know is there any limit for views or not? do you have any idea ?

Comment: if I remember it right, Eclipse started warning when there were 80 views in your layout, but now I think, as Graham pointed it, it's all about available memory.

Comment: Ok so basically 80 views are recommend but if you are using more then 80 views so use on your risk. am i right ?

Comment: you may face performance issue in some device having low memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking the "limit" is 80.

Lint reports the following when you have too many views in a layout :-

> AndroidLintTooManyViews
>
> Description
>
> Layout has too many views  Using too many views in a single layout is bad 
>   for performance. Consider using compound drawables or other tricks for 
>   reducing the number of views in this layout.  The maximum view count 
>   defaults to 80 but can be configured with the environment variable 
>   ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT.

However, I was using a table layout which blew my number of views by a few (mainly TextViews) and I have had no problems. I didn't bother to change the ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT variable.

Answer (score 4):

There are no certain things in android.You can use maximum views as much as you can.But one thing that needs to keep in mind, there should be maximum 3 level hierarchy.