# Recycleview under NestedScrollview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I put my `RecyclerView` under `NestedScrollView`. If `RecyclerView` data is small then it's working fine but if data is more than 10,000, `Android OS` default pop come and ask for `wait` or `close` the application. If I remove my `NestedRecyclerView` then it's working fine. My question is what is the better way to put the layout in `ScrollView`

**This is my layout**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/totstock_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/totstockrelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockSelectBox"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Warehouse"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockwarehouse"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_text"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/totstockrelativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockSelectBox1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Customer"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockcustomer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_text"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/totrelativeLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totSelectBox2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Item Name"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/totitemautotext"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_text"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/totstocksearch_wms"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@color/mdtp_light_gray"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/datahorizontal2tot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/datahorizontal1tot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/datahorizontaltot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockitemsku"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Item SKU"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockstockitemname"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Item Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockbrandname"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Brand Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockgrdname"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Grade Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockgrnqty"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="GRN Quantity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockpickqty"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Pick List Quantity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockavailqty"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Available Quantity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockputawayqty"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Put Away Quantity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockorderqty"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Order Quantity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockdamage"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Damage"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totstockdispatchhqty"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Dispatch Quantity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewline1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/totstockwmsrecyclerview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totstocknorecord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Record Found"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think it's the `RecyclerView` or the `NestedScrollView` that is the issue per se. Your view hierarchy is huge. Try to remove all those `TextView`s and `AutoCompleteTextView` - basically everything but the `NestedScrollView` and the `RecyclerView` and see if it still causes issues with a large dataset. I think what you're experiencing is a limitation in how many views that can be drawn on the screen. I don't remember the max number, but I think you're really close to this limit with your incredibly huge view hierarchy.

Comment: is it so? there is any limit of layout?

Comment: but when i remove my `scrollview` it's working fine

Comment: The limit is theoretically speaking 80 views per layout - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153362/maximum-limit-of-view-in-android-layout-xml
If you remove the ScrollView (is that the `NestedScrollView` or the `HorizontalScrollView`?) then that's what I would examine first.

Comment: if i remove my `NestedScrollView` then everything working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use scrolling views as parent and child

instead you should use recyclerview with multiple rows like this:

http://arjunu.com/2015/10/android-recyclerview-with-different-cardviews/

Comment: You should if you need it.

Comment: no, he can put other views in an item of recyclerview

Comment: that's my question. how?

Comment: no that is not usable for me. Actually i need to scroll my screen `verticall` as well as `horizontal`

Comment: i didn't saw any horizontal scrollview in your views but yes you can do that this way, just in those views that you want to be horizontal put them in a recyclerview with horizontal layout manager

Comment: `RecycleView` itself  under horizontal view