# Maximum number of components per activity Android

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-components

Is there a limit as to how many components an android activity can hold? And how does it affect the application's performance? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum limit of view in Android layout xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153362/maximum-limit-of-view-in-android-layout-xml)

Answer (score 1):

No there is no as such limit

The more the nested heirarchy the more time it will take to inflate the layout
Don't use unnecessary view goups if you can do that with a constraint layout